# Active Admin: How to Left align buttons by default

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

as it is explained in the following image. Active admin buttons are right align by default.

[image]

I want to align them to left by default, is there any setting in Active Admin to achieve this ?

Comment: yes open your inspect and see your the code then add text-align: left something similar to #header ul.tabs {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

Comment: @nourza thanks it helped and I'm able to align buttons to left

Comment: Great :) please accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can align them to left by default by opening your inspect then see your the code then add text-align: left something similar to

`#header ul.tabs {  display: table-cell; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; }`